# Creating txt file using Pentaho

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I'm currently trying to create txt files from all tables in the dbo schema

I have like 200s-300s tables there, so it would takes up too much times to create it manually..

I was thinking for creating a loop.

so as example (using AdventureWorks2019) :

```
select t.name as table_name
from sys.tables t
where schema_name(t.schema_id) = 'Person' 
order by table_name;
```

This would get all the table name within the Person schema.
So I would loop :

```
Table input : select * from ${table_name}
```

But then i realized that for txt files, i need to declare all the field and their data types in pentaho, so it would become a problems.
Any ideas how to do this "backup" txt files?

Answer (score 0):

Using Metadata Injection and more queries to the schema catalog tables in SQL Server. You not only need to retrieve the table name, you would need to afterwards retrieve the columns in that table and the data types, and inject that information (metadata) to the text output step.

You have in the samples directory of your spoon installation an example on how to use Metadata Injection, use it, along with the documentation, to build a simple example (the check to generate a transformation with the metadata you have injected is of great use to debug)

I have something similar to copy data from one database to another, both in Oracle, but with SQL Server you have similar catalog tables as in Oracle to retrieve the information you need. I created a simple, almost empty transformation to read one table and write to another. This transformation has almost no information, only the database origin in the Table Input step and the target database in the Table Output step:
[image: Transformation to inject]

And then I have a second transformation where I fill up all the information (metadata) to inject: The query to perform in the Table Input step, and all the data I need in the Table Output: Target table, if I need to truncate before inserting, the columns from (stream field) and to (Table field):
[image: Transformation injecting the information]